# Mongoose/JS - Jump out of code, skipping any then blocks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

If I have a call to check whether a particular ID exists - how do i exit the entire thing if an error is found right at the start.

I know I can do it with a if-else block, however is there a 'easier to read' 1 line way.

e.g.:

```
Question.find({_id: req.headers['questionid']}, {question:1, tags:1},
                        function(err, foundQ) {


if(!err) {
      //skip everything below including the then
}

})
.then(function(foundQ){
    //Some more stuff here
})
```

Also, fyi - I'm using the Q framework in another section of code - so if there's an alternative method there someone could guide me to could also help.

Comment: I think err here does not suggest that you were not able to find the record, it could occur in case of a connection failure or another similar issue. foundQ would be null if you didn't find it. In case or err it should automatically go to the `.catch` or `.fail` call, since its returning a promise.

Comment: Ok so you're saying i just need to a `.catch` or `.fail` after the last then block then code in there?

Comment: You need to have a `.catch` in any case ... anything could happen and should have code in place to catch it. If you had an err then you will go into the catch block skipping all the `then's`. Are you looking for a way to skip the `then` calls on purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break out of a function, chained with `.then` and not invoke the following `.then`'s, you can throw an error `throw new Error('this is an error');`. But with mongoose, and promises, you should be able to use that way instead and just do `.find().exec().then().catch();`, and your errors should end up in `.catch`. No need have a callback in the `find`.

```
Question.find({_id: req.headers['questionid']}, {question:1, tags:1}).exec().
.then(function(foundQ){
    //Some more stuff here
})
.catch(function(err){
})
```

Comment: Thanks so in your example above - you are using Mongoose's `.find().exec().then().catch();` way? If so where is `exec()` ?

Comment: According to what i'm reading here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html I guess the answer to my question above is no

Comment: @userMod2: That code just shows a throw, from the original suggestion. I will edit it to clearify.

Comment: Awesome - got it now.
So i guess thats always the way to go?
I dont see when callbacks would be useful in this sitauation now?

Comment: If you do it the other way with `find(criteria, callback);` then you can just `return` from your callback if you want to exit. But you nested find().then() in your question.

Comment: I've tried the above code but even when theres a valid `questionid` its still going to the catch statement - any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update - it worked on, I had a syntax error with a closing bracket. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

According to mongoose docs;

`find` method returns Query object.

`exec` method returns a promise.

So `Question.find().exec().then()` usage should work as you expected.

---

*References;*

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec

Comment: i just read http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html and basically i understand that using exec allows me to execute the query object at the later time. But i presume I'll still have to through a new error and then catch it. So how would `Question.find().exec().then()` work/help?

Comment: may be I misunderstood you requirements, I mean your then block completely skipped, so I only pointed which object returns according to your used methods.